# BeautifulSoup: scrape HTML only accessible after clicking jvector map in the same URL

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jvectormap

I am trying to write a python script to automate some tasks I do daily on the Groupons commerce interface site(for sellers), they have an api for orders but not to po's so I am trying to write something to scrape the data.

However to choose your country you need to log in to you are presented with a jvector map which you have to click the region to access the [login page](https://scm.commerceinterface.com/accounts/login/?next=/).

you cant right click the page to view the source however you can inspect the element of the country/ies you want to click.

can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the map is not available in the page source because it is being rendered using AJAX.

You can still scrape the website using a combination of a headless browser (like [PhantomJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/what-is-phantomjs-and-how-is-it-used)) and [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (to manipulate the DOM).

When you click inspect element on any country you'll see code like this

```
<path d="M384.26,87.96l-0.51,2.35l0.08,0.28l2.61,2.58l-2.99,2.83l-
7.16,2.72l-2.08,0.7l-9.51,-1.71l1.89,-1.36l-0.07,-0.53l-
4.4,-1.59l3.33,-0.59l0.25,-0.32l-0.11,-1.2l-0.25,-0.27l-
4.82,-0.88l1.38,-2.2l3.54,-0.57l3.8,2.74l0.33,0.01l3.68,-2.18l3.02,
1.12l0.25,-0.02l4.01,-2.18l3.72,0.27Z" data-code="IS" fill="#dadada" 
fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" 
fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element">
</path>
```

The code for each country is similar except for the 'd' and 'data-code' attribute. Both of these are unique for each country. You can use selenium webdriver to find the element using this unique attribute and then use the click method to go to the login page. I imagine the rest of the website also loads stuff in AJAX so you could stick to a Selenium, PhantomJS and BeautifulSoup combination to simulate user login (using your credentials, I don't have any so I couldn't try that) and then scrape whatever results you need to.

Hope this helps in getting started!

BONUS: To understand what those values of 'd' attribute mean, [read this](http://anshumania.github.io/delhi-map/howtocreate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, also the link. I was having some trouble with the selenium driver, ill have another crack. :)